# How can I simplify my function and make it more pythonic?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have written a Python function for some post processing in my text recognition algorithm. It works fine, but it seems to be kind of lengthy and has many `if`-`else`-conditions. I am looking for a way to simplify my code:

```
def postProcessing(new_s): #new_s is a list
  import string
    
  new_s=removeFrontLetters(new_s) #This function has to be called first
 
  if all(ch in string.digits for ch in new_s[:4]): #checking if first 4 elements are digits.
    
    if all(ch in string.ascii_letters for ch in new_s[4:5]): #checking if the [4] and [5] are letters
      
      if len(new_s)>=7:         
        if new_s[6]=='C': 
          
          new_s=new_s[:7] #if length>=7 and the [6] =='C' the reversed of the first 7 elements has to be returned.
          new_s=list(reversed(new_s)) 
          return(new_s)

          
        else:
          new_s=new_s[:6] #if length>=7 but the [6] =!'C' the reversed of the first 6 elements has to be returned.
          new_s=list(reversed(new_s))

          return(new_s)
      

      else:
        new_s=list(reversed(new_s)) #if length<7, the reversed of the given list has to be returned.
        return(new_s)
    else:
      print('not valid') #if the [4] and [5] are not letters, it is not valid
  else:
    print('not valid') #if the [:4] are not digits, it is not valid
```

This seems very beginner-level and lengthy. I am a beginner, but I am trying to improve my function. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: We can already notice that there is a potential silent bug in your code. `new_s[4:5]` gives you the 5th element only, inside a list.

Comment: What is your function do??? Can you tell us so we can provide some other solutions?

Comment: @codester_09 this gets a list in first. and it should check if the first 4 elements are digits and the 5th and 6th are letters. If this first two conditions are satisfied, and if the length of the list >= 7, it should check the 7th element. if 7th element is 'C' it should return the  reverse of the [:7].  if not 'C' or if  length=<7, it should return reverse [:6].

Comment: a basic simplification: `all(ch in string.digits for ch in new_s[:4])` is also `"".join(new_s[:4]).isdigit()` (and `all(ch in string.ascii_letters for ch in new_s[4:5])` is `new_s[4].isalpha()`

Comment: `#if the [4] and [5] are not letters` you're not testing `[5]`

Answer (score 2):

You can invert your if statements and use early returns to reduce the indentation of your code.

```
def postProcessing(new_s):  # new_s is a list
    import string

    new_s = removeFrontLetters(new_s)  # This function has to be called first

    if not all(ch in string.digits for ch in new_s[:4]):  # checking if first 4 elements are digits.
        raise ValueError("First four elements must be digits")
    
    if not all(ch in string.ascii_letters for ch in new_s[4:5]):  # checking if the [4] and [5] are letters
        raise ValueError("First elements 4 and 5 must be digits")
    
    if len(new_s) <= 7:
        new_s = list(reversed(new_s))  # if length<7, the reversed of the given list has to be returned.
        return (new_s)
    
    if new_s[6] == 'C':

        new_s = new_s[
                :7]  # if length>=7 and the [6] =='C' the reversed of the first 7 elements has to be returned.
        new_s = list(reversed(new_s))
        return (new_s)

    new_s = new_s[:6]  # if length>=7 but the [6] =!'C' the reversed of the first 6 elements has to be returned.
    new_s = list(reversed(new_s))
    return (new_s)
```

Comment: I assume leaving the obvious `4:5` issue is on purpose?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite neat you ask 'the world' for advise.  Did you know there's a dedicated stackexchange site for this?  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Unless you insist writing Python code for this, it seems that you need a regular expression here.

So some tips:

- use regex for pattern matching
- use variables to express what an expression means
- use exceptions instead of an 'invalid value' string
- separate the 'parsing' from the processing to keep functions small and focused
- use doctest to document and test small functions

```py
def post_process(new_s):
    """
    reverse a string (with a twist)

    what follows is a doctest.  You can run it with
    $ python -m doctest my_python_file.py

    >>> post_process('1234abCdef')
    'Cba4321'
    >>> post_process('1234abdef')
    'ba4321'
    """

    cmds = {
      'C': cmd_c,
      '': cmd_none
    }

    command, content = command_and_content(new_s)
    process = cmds[command]
    return process(content)


def cmd_c(content):
  return 'C' + "".join(reversed(content))
def cmd_none(content):
  return "".join(reversed(content))
```

The `command_and_content` function replaces the parsing logic:

```py
def command_and_content(new_s):
    # get help on https://regex101.com/ to find the
    # regular expression for four digits and two letters
    digits_then_ascii = re.compile(r"(\d{4}[a-z]{2})(C?)(.*)")
    if match := digits_then_ascii.match(new_s):
      content = match.group(1)
      command = match.group(2)
      return command, content

    # pylint will ask you to not use an else clause after a return
    # Also, Python advises exceptions for notifying erroneous input
    raise ValueError(new_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the context you provided, I assume that all this processing can happen in-place (i.e. without the need to allocate additional memory). The benefit of lists is that they are mutable, so you can actually do all your operations in-place.

This adheres to the style conventions ([PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)) and uses correct type annotations ([PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)):

```py
from string import digits, ascii_letters


def remove_front_letters(new_s: list[str]) -> None:
    ...
    raise NotImplementedError


def post_processing(new_s: list[str]) -> None:
    remove_front_letters(new_s)
    if any(ch not in digits for ch in new_s[:4]):
        raise ValueError("The first 4 characters must be digits")
    if any(ch not in ascii_letters for ch in new_s[4:6]):
        raise ValueError("The 5th and 6th characters must be letters")
    if len(new_s) >= 7:
        if new_s[6] == 'C':
            del new_s[7:]
        else:
            del new_s[6:]
    new_s.reverse()
```

If you *do* want a new list, you can just call this function with a `.copy()` of your input list.

References: [list methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists); [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

**PS**: If you use Python version 3.8 or lower, instead of `list[str]` you'll need to use `typing.List[str]`.

Also someone mentioned the possibility of replacing the iteration via `all()` (or `any()`) with a `"".join(...).isdigit()` for example. While this is certainly also correct and technically less code, I am not sure it is necessarily more readable. More importantly it creates a new string in the process, which I don't think is necessary.

By the way, you *could* even reduce that conditional deletion of list elements to a one liner like this:

```py
...
    if len(new_s) >= 7:
        del new_s[7 if new_s[6] == 'C' else 6:]
    new_s.reverse()
```

But I would argue that this is worse because it is less readable. Personal preference I guess.